# How to protect PDF content from getting downloaded and view in the browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mozilla

The issue is that I have tried implementing a mechanism that the PDF files are first compress using https://pdf.io service then its been converted to base64 using https://base64.guru/converter/encode/pdf service and uploaded the txt file using the FTP on a XYZ Server.

I then wrote a small wrapper converting the base64 back to pdf and loading that up in a CANVAS. This all idea was done to avoid:
* Illegal Save As
* Stopping Printing
* Sharing PDF URLs

The issue I am facing is that the time taken to perform the last activity to grab the encrypted txt file and convert back to PDF takes alot of time specially on a lower internet connection it takes a lot time and the file size if exceeds a certain MB like 75mb the file drops an error.

I have used btoa() and atob() functions available in javascript after a long research and possible ways.

If you guys have any alternate way out let me know and please help me.

**Background**

I have already done with the EMBEDDED URLs hiding the bar, GOOGLE DRIVE PDF restricting and much more available on stack-overflow solutions and other forums too.

But none of them got the thing secure. I also blocked the VIEW SOURCE CONTROL option on the page but still using 3rd party page inscription or saving page out creates a door to access the URL mention in the iframe or canvas url or the js files etc.

Comment: You can't protect anything if your client can access it. You can only make it harder. Take YouTube for example, do you think that they want someone to be able to download their videos and watch without ads, but there is youtube-dl that keep updating the scrapper to get the videos.

Comment: Yes, I can understand but I need help how it can be done. So things can be make more better. thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try to render each page as png image (on the server) and write front-end to paginate the images. You can use canvas to render the images. And you can use CSRF protection with httpOnly cookie. I'm not sure but I think that this will prevent **scraping** of the page and render the images by some script, at least it will make things harder (as I said it will be impossible to protect client site application).